# How to call user/group IDs in Linux bash scripts

Tags: linux, bash

I have this bash script. I run it with the following command: `sudo ./install.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

MYSQL_PASS="password"

USER="500"
SUPERUSER="0"

sudo -u ${USER} echo -e "Installing docker-compose from GitHub Latest release..." \
\
&& sudo -u ${SUPERUSER} mkdir -p /opt/bin \
&& sudo -u ${SUPERUSER} curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.5.2/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /opt/bin/docker-compose \
&& sudo -u ${SUPERUSER} chmod +x /opt/bin/docker-compose \
&& sudo -u ${USER} echo -e "docker-compose installed, verifying..." \
&& sudo -u ${USER} docker-compose -v \
\
&& sudo -u ${USER} echo -e "Creating folder structure..." \
&& sudo -u ${USER} mkdir -p ~/mysql ~/sqlbackup ~/work/lemp ~/www \
\
&& sudo -u ${USER} echo -e "Cloning git repo into \"~/work/lemp\"..." \
&& sudo -u ${USER} git clone https://github.com/DJviolin/LEMP.git ~/work/lemp \
\
&& sudo -u ${USER} echo -e "Showing working directory..." \
&& sudo -u ${USER} ls -al ~/work/lemp \
\
&& sudo -u ${USER} echo -e "Starting docker images and containers generation..." \
&& sudo -u ${USER} echo -e "\
# Set MySQL Root Password\n\
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASS}" > ~/work/lemp/mariadb/mariadb.env \
&& sudo -u ${USER} cat ~/work/lemp/mariadb/mariadb.env \
&& sudo -u ${USER} docker-compose build ~/work/lemp \
\
&& sudo -u ${USER} echo -e "LEMP stack has built...\nRun the service with ./service-start.sh command." \
&& sudo -u ${USER} echo -e "All done! Exiting..."
```

Calling the user `core` as `500` and `root` as `0` not working. I've got the following error:

```
sudo: unknown user: 500
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

The reason why I want to use user or group numbers, because I want to make it multiplatform (would be nice if it can choose between 500 or 1000, because I read some linux distros' default user is 1000, but in my case is 500).

Can we detect which user started to run this script as `sudo`? Because probably this is the way to go on a multi-user linux.

EDIT:

This is the script without the need of the superuser privileges, making a new path variable under the user's home folder:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

echo -e "Installing docker-compose from GitHub Latest release..."

mkdir -p ~/bin
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.5.2/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > ~/bin/docker-compose
chmod +x ~/bin/docker-compose
export PATH="~/bin:$PATH"
echo -e "docker-compose installed, verifying..."
docker-compose -v

echo -e "Creating folder structure..."
mkdir -p ~/mysql ~/sqlbackup ~/work/lemp ~/www

echo -e "Cloning git repo into \"~/work/lemp\"..."
git clone https://github.com/DJviolin/LEMP.git ~/work/lemp

echo -e "Showing working directory..."
ls -al ~/work/lemp

echo -e "Starting docker images and containers generation..."
echo -e "\
# Set MySQL Root Password\n\
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=`openssl rand -base64 37 | sed -e 's/^\(.\{37\}\).*/\1/g'`" > ~/work/lemp/mariadb/mariadb.env
cat ~/work/lemp/mariadb/mariadb.env

echo -e "LEMP stack has built...\nRun the service with ./service-start.sh command." \
echo -e "All done! Exiting..."
```

Comment: I don't understand why you insist on invoking `sudo` to perform a command *as the current user*. Just run the command directly, and only use `sudo` to impersonate `root`.

Comment: Running the script without sudo and placing sudo commands for docker-compose didn't worked for me under CoreOS. I've got `Permission denied` error. But I don't want to run every single line as superuser, so that's why I invoking the normal user most of the lines. The `/opt/bin` dir (where I copying docker-compose) only can used by the superuser.

Comment: `sudo echo > output_file` is incorrect.  The `echo` runs as superuser, but the redirection to a file is done by the current user.  You should use `echo | sudo tee output_file >/dev/null` instead.

Comment: But I agree with @FrédéricHamidi: no need to use sudo every time. Also, no need to use `&&`, use `set -e` instead

Comment: The other option is to ditching sudo from everything and add a new folder to the PATH under `~/bin/docker-compose`. Can I invoke an user folder to path this way or is it making conflict in multi-user environment?

Comment: Sorry, the correct folder is `~/bin` that I want to add. docker-compose is the executible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the `sudo` [man pages](http://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.13/sudo.man.html):

> -u user, --user=user
>   Run the command as a user other than the default target user (usually root ). The user may be either a user name or **a numeric user ID (UID) prefixed with the ‘#’ character (e.g. #0 for UID 0)**. When running commands as a UID, many shells require that the ‘#’ be escaped with a backslash (‘\’). Some security policies may restrict UIDs to those listed in the password database. The sudoers policy allows UIDs that are not in the password database as long as the targetpw option is not set. Other security policies may not support this.

Because `#` is also used to begin comments, you'll either want to escape it with a backslash or quote it.  For example `sudo -u "#${USER}"` or `sudo -u \#${USER}`